# A Simple Summation

Tags: riddle, word, cipher, rhyme

Here I am with another rhyming riddle. This time I have encoded it with a vigenere cipher. But don't despair, because I'm also giving you the key!
(I hope this doesn't make it too easy.)

> emws mpjk fcbi kgubm lzm qvby htxyrpx
>   npn lufotwmt asizhhw xerhq bozskduig
>   f uzubuz bzq dm wdayamtj nnwm
>   f wvixxvvut pwv yaavhoh bimx dvtniz
>   q yuvpeis ltfxro emrm sdj xfxj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deusovi has decoded the riddle, to which the answer is:

> **DANGER**

First line

> *When down vith wrath the risk abounds*
>
>  This is a cryptic clue: D for down and ANGER, wrath. To take a risk means to expose oneself to danger.

Second line

> *The sawbones endless saint surrounds.*
>
>  And another cryptic clue: DR for doctor or "sawbones" surrounds ANGE[l], an endless saint: D(ANGE)R.

Third line

> *A curser who is somewhat meek,*
>
>  Someone who says "Dang!" could be a danger.

Fourth line

> *A tunesmith who perhaps goes squeak,*
>
>  This refers to Danger Mouse, a [musician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_Mouse_(musician)) and a [cartoon series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_Mouse_(1981_TV_series)).

Last line

> *A tangled garden this you seek.*
>
>  Danger is an anagram of GARDEN, as Deusovi found out.

Title

> The title is probably related to danger or the code somehow, but I haven't found out how.

Comment: Well done! The title is meant to say that you simply add the two pieces together to get the riddle. Congrats.

Answer (score 7):

### Partial answer: riddle decoded, not solved

The key is

> the introductory text itself. Decoding as Vigenere, then shifting back 1 gives:
>
>  when down vith wrath the risk abounds
>  the sawbones endless saint surrounds
>  a curser who is somewhat meek
>  a tunesmith who perhaps goes squeak
>  a tangled garden this you seek

Thoughts on the riddle:

> The second line seems very cryptic-clue-ish: put a synonym for "sawbones" inside a synonym of "saint" without its last letter.
>  The last line also seems cryptic - a "tangled garden" could perhaps be "danger".
>  The "v" in "vith" rather than "with" may be a clue. It could also be a typo, but I'm not sure that Hugh would make that kind of mistake.

Comment: Great start! And, sorry, it is a typo. My bad. I'll fix it in the question.